# Every command in a ssh session delays

Tags: ssh

I sshed to a ssh server, every command I exec has a delay, a simple `w` then return, it will take 1 second to response, `UseDNS no` has been set, and server is idle.

I googled and tried some methods, but all failed.

What maybe the cause?

Comment: `UseDNS no` only affects the initial establishment of the ssh connection, nothing more. What is your network latency to the server? What is the disk IO and CPU load like on the server?

Comment: Server is totally idle, and network either

Comment: what ssh client are you using to connect? what options?

Comment: MacOSX 10.7.5's native ssh command, `OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011`, no options, directly `ssh user@host`